# spring data reactive: where is located entity annotation?

Tags: spring-boot, spring-data, spring-webflux

I'm running in a issue. `@Entity` annotation is not found.

Here my pom related dependencies:

```xml
    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-dependencies</artifactId>
                <version>2.7.0</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-r2dbc</artifactId>
    </dependency>
```

I was trying to set `@javax.persistence.Entity` to my `Person` class.
But compiler is not able to look up it.

Which dependency am I forgoting?

Answer (score 0):

add JPA

```
   <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
    </dependency>
```